# Can I read Vaults secrets?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I understand the whole idea behind Hashi Vault is to store secrets securely. But for debugging purposes, is there a way to view or print the dynamic secrets generated by the transit or AWS secrets engines and others ?

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a while ago, but:

In general, it depends, but a likely no; the vault is designed to be very restrictive with its secrets, but implementation will vary based on engine

To the two engines you mentioned,

The transit engine does support exportable keys so that maybe one way to get the desired output. But you would also need the data to decrypt.

The AWS requires [configuration](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/aws) to connect to AWS, so it may be possible to Query the config to the info. However, I am not sure as I do not make use of the AWS secret engine much.

Both these methods will need access with significant "sudo" permissions or root vault user.

Finally, if you have enough of the unseal keys, access to Vault's back end, and an understanding of vaults inner workings,  you could directly look at vaults storage.